# How can I print several ASCII art graphics horizontally instead of vertically?

Tags: python

I am working on a yahtzee project, and want to display dice text graphics on screen from left to right, and not up and down

This is the code that I have now:

```
import random

die1 = random.randint(1,6)
die2 = random.randint(1,6)
die3 = random.randint(1,6)
die4 = random.randint(1,6)
die5 = random.randint(1,6)

def diepic(die):
    if die == 1:
        print ("=========")
        print ("|       |")
        print ("|   O   |")
        print ("|       |")
        print ("=========")
    elif die == 2:
        print ("=========")
        print ("| O     |")
        print ("|       |")
        print ("|     O |")
        print ("=========")
    elif die == 3:
        print ("=========")
        print ("| O     |")
        print ("|   O   |")
        print ("|     O |")
        print ("=========")
    elif die == 4:
        print ("=========")
        print ("| O   O |")
        print ("|       |")
        print ("| O   O |")
        print ("=========")
    elif die == 5:
        print ("=========")
        print ("| O   O |")
        print ("|   O   |")
        print ("| O   O |")
        print ("=========")
    else:
        print ("=========")
        print ("| O   O |")
        print ("| O   O |")
        print ("| O   O |")
        print ("=========")

diepic(die1)
diepic(die2)
diepic(die3)
diepic(die4)
diepic(die5)
```

This will print out the random dice selections top to bottom, but I would like to print them out at the very top of the screen from left to right.  Is there an easy way to accomplish this?  This code will print it out like:

```
=========
|       |
|   O   |
|       |
=========
=========
| O     |
|       |
|     O |
=========
=========
| O     |
|   O   |
|     O |
=========
=========
| O   O |
|       |
| O   O |
=========
=========
| O   O |
|   O   |
| O   O |
=========
```

and I want it like this:

```
========= ========= ========= ========= =========
|       | | O     | | O     | | O   O | | O   O |
|   O   | |       | |   O   | |       | |   O   |
|       | |     O | |     O | | O   O | | O   O |
========= ========= ========= ========= =========
```

And then the game can be continued underneath the dice.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quick snippet for this.

First, redefine your function to return a list containing each line of the of the dice graphic rather than printing them directly.

```py
def diepic(die):
    if die == 1:
        return ["=========",
                "|       |",
                "|   O   |",
                "|       |",
                "=========",]
    elif die == 2:
        return ["=========",
                "| O     |",
                "|       |",
                "|     O |",
                "=========",]
    elif die == 3:
        return ["=========",
                "| O     |",
                "|   O   |",
                "|     O |",
                "=========",]
    elif die == 4:
        return ["=========",
                "| O   O |",
                "|       |",
                "| O   O |",
                "=========",]
    elif die == 5:
        return ["=========",
                "| O   O |",
                "|   O   |",
                "| O   O |",
                "=========",]
    else:
        return ["=========",
                "| O   O |",
                "| O   O |",
                "| O   O |",
                "=========",]
```

Then you can `zip` and `join` the elements to concatenate the different lines horizontally:

```py
import random
    
print('\n'.join(map('  '.join, zip(*[diepic(random.randint(1,6)) for i in range(5)]))))
```

example output:

```
=========  =========  =========  =========  =========
| O     |  | O   O |  | O     |  |       |  | O   O |
|       |  |       |  |   O   |  |   O   |  | O   O |
|     O |  | O   O |  |     O |  |       |  | O   O |
=========  =========  =========  =========  =========
```

Annotated code for the final part. As this is a comprehension, it should be read bottom to top:

```
print(                                                  # print the whole
      '\n'.join(                                        # join the lines
                map('  '.join,                          # join the swapped chunks
                    zip(*[                              # swap the chunks
                          diepic(random.randint(1,6))   # return the chunks per die
                                 for i in range(5)      # repeat 5 times
                         ]
                        )
                    )
               )
     )
```

Comment: The parentheses around the strings are pointless. Also it's probably worth expanding the line to explain what's actually happening, because it could be quite confusing to a beginner.

Comment: @Pranav yes they are not needed, I edited OP's code programmatically, I forgot to remove the parentheses ;)

Comment: I like the use of lists. I would personally prefer a brute force approach along the lines of `for i in range(len(die1)): print(die1[i], ' ', die2[i], ' ', die3[i], ' ', die4[i], ' ', die5[i]) as it would be easier for me to figure out what the code does when I read it again in the future.