# The codes will breakline eventhough i asked it not to

Tags: python, line-breaks

```
from datetime import date

now = date.today()
today_date = '   _____        _              _      ___      _____      _    _ \n  |_   _|__  __| |__ _ _  _ __( )___ |   \ __ |_   _|__  (_)__(_)\n    | |/ _ \/ _` / _` | || (_-</(_-< | |) / _` || |/ -_) | (_-<_ \n    |_|\___/\__,_\__,_|\_, /__/ /__/ |___/\__,_||_|\___| |_/__(_)\n                       |__/                                      '

one = '  _ \n / |\n | |\n |_| '
two = '  ___ \n |_  )\n  / / \n /___|'
three = ' ____\n |__ /\n  |_ \ \n |___/'
four = '  _ _  \n | | | \n |_  _|\n   |_| '
five = '  ___ \n | __|\n |__ \ \n |___/'

six = '   __ \n  / / \n / _ \ \n \___/'
seven = '  ____ \n |__  |\n   / / \n  /_/  ' 
eight = '  ___ \n ( _ )\n / _ \ \n \___/'
nine = '  ___ \n / _ \ \n \_, / \n  /_/ '
zero = '   __  \n  /  \ \n | () |\n  \__/ '

dt_string = now.strftime("%d%m")
print("date and time =", dt_string)

if dt_string[0] == 0:
    print(zero)
elif dt_string[0] == '1':
    print(one)
elif dt_string[0] == '2':
    print(two)
elif dt_string[0] == '3':
    print(three)
elif dt_string[0] == '4':
    print(four)
elif dt_string[0] == '5':
    print(five)
elif dt_string[0] == '6':
    print(six)
elif dt_string[0] == '7':
    print(seven)
elif dt_string[0] == '8':
    print(eight)
elif dt_string[0] == '9':
    print(nine)

if dt_string[1] == '0':
    print(zero)
elif dt_string[1] == '1':
    print(one)
elif dt_string[1] == '2':
    print(two)
elif dt_string[1] == '3':
    print(three)
elif dt_string[1] == '4':
    print(four)
elif dt_string[1] == '5':
    print(five)
elif dt_string[1] == '6':
    print(six)
elif dt_string[1] == '7':
    print(seven)
elif dt_string[1] == '8':
    print(eight)
elif dt_string[1] == '9':
    print(nine)
```

Its a simply date time calender thingy, i want it to print day/month....but the character will breakline...

I've tried print(one, end='') but it still does not work

I feel its because i'm using ascii characters.

*also this is for a competition and were only allowed to use time library:(

Comment: Did you try `sep=""` instead of `end=""`?

Comment: yep, still dosen't work

Comment: You can store characters in a huge matrix initialized to all spaces (e.g. `matrix = [[' '] * width] * height`) and then print the matrix line by line all at once, or move the cursor using ANSI escape sequence, which can simulate `←` `↑` `→` `↓` keystrokes.

Comment: well for one you have `if dt_string[0] == 0:` instead of `if dt_string[0] == '0':` maybe that's something

Comment: If I understand correctly this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69272292/how-can-i-print-several-ascii-art-graphics-horizontally-instead-of-vertically